# Create blank image in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm trying to create a blank image (later to be filled) using OpenCV, but it has to be in the same size with the predefined image as a new image. I tried the following code:

(image would be the picture of lena which is successfully displayed)

```
    Mat lena1(Size(image.cols,image.rows),CV_8UC1);
    namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    //imshow( "Display Image", image );
    imshow("blank", lena1);
```

But for some reason, it still shows "image" and not lena1 (that would be the blank image with the same sizes of the predefined image).

Thank you!

Comment: You create the blank picture correctly, but I don't see any code to actually populate your matrix with lena1 pixels, so of course `imshow` displays blank picture.

Comment: This `lena1(Size(image.cols,image.rows),CV_8UC1);` is not correct way to create blank image. It initializes image with random values or perhaps we should say it leaves image as uninitialized, you should use overload taking `Scalar` with all components set to 0:  `lena1(Size(image.cols,image.rows),CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar());`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create a blank image(image filled with zeros) use cv::Mat::zeros(). It will create a matrix with the dimension and type of your choice that is filled with zeros.

In your case, use the following code,

```
Mat lena1 = Mat::zeros(Size(image.cols,image.rows),CV_8UC1);
```

To fill that with a pre-loaded image,

```
image.copyTo(lena1);
```

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly that, thanks a lot, fully solved!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an image with a single color you can do that too

```
Mat blueImage(cols, rows, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
```

Comment: I think it should be CV_8UC3 and not CV_8UC1 and this code will produce a red image. Blue image code:


`Mat blueImage(cols, rows, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255, 0, 0));`